# When does a new window object get created?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

From what I understand *The window object represents a window containing a DOM document.*

So does that mean I will only get a "new" window object when the page is refreshed, or window.location is changed (either explicitly or through history api)?

I have a webpage with an iframe. i want to attach certain objects to the iframe.contentWindow while the parent is controlling what the iframe location is. For example:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("appFrame");
iframe.contentWindow.location.href = "my other website";
iframe.contentWindow.someFunctionHandler = function() {};
```

But in the javascript of my iframe, i can never get the

```
window.someFunctionhandler.
```

Comment: You would never get a "new" window object, it's always the same for the whole run time.

Comment: On browsers, you can create window objects using iframes or `window.open`.

Comment: What is the context of the question?

Comment: @zerkms: Except you get a different one in each frame

Comment: You will want to wait for the iframe to load before you use its window.

Comment: @Bergi my comment mostly addressed the previous revision that did not mention iframes.